# NSDictionary only return one object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

There is a this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url    
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication 
         annotation:(id)annotation 
{
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

...but it is deprecated, so I replaced it with this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
            options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options
{
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:options//Only string
                                                       annotation:options];//id
}
```

How do I take from NSDictionary only string object, and similarly with id.

Comment: Read the documentation for `UIApplicationDelegate application:openURL:options:`. See what it says about the `options` parameter.

Comment: See also: [The XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log or debug inside the method and see the values.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
  NSLog(@"sourceApplication: %@,annotation: %@",sourceApplication,annotation);
  //return ...
}
```

The log is: `sourceApplication: com.apple.SafariViewService,annotation: (null)`

And in remain method:

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)options{
NSLog(@"%@", options);
//return ...
```

}

The log is:

```
UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsOpenInPlaceKey = 0;
    UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey = "com.apple.SafariViewService";
```

So you can replace your code like that

```
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:[options valueForKey:@"UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"]
                                                       annotation:nil];
```

But I think using the first method is ok, don't need to use this method :D
Or you might read more about Apple docs on this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar

Happy coding;

Comment: No, this is wrong. 1) Don't use `valueForKey:` to get a value from a dictionary. Use `objectForKey:` unless you have a clear and specific reason to be using KVC. 2) Don't hardcode the key as a string. iOS provides a proper constant for that key. See `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey`. So the proper syntax to get the source application from `options` is: `options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]`.

Comment: And this answer neglected to show how to get the annotation from `options`.

Comment: @maddy Yes, I see. It's just a temporary thinking, and not good, thank for advice.

Answer (score 0):

It is the syntax of Objective C light weight generics. This feature is mainly included for fixing Objective C - Swift interoperability issues.

`NSDictionary<NSString *,id>` means, the dictionary keys should be of type NSString and it's value can be any type of object (id).

Below is the example of getting values from `NSDictionary<NSString *,id>`, I hope this will help you how to extract NSString object and id according to the response you are getting from Facebook login.

```
    //Assign Generic Value.
    float fltT = 98564.5f;
    NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, id> *_generic;
    _generic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    _generic[@"genericValue"] = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fltT];
    NSLog(@"Assigned Generic Value:%@",_generic);

    //Access generic values from NSMutableDictionary
    NSLog(@"Access Generic Value:%@",_generic[@"genericValue"]);
```

Here is the output log:-

[image]

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question? The question is asking how to use the 2nd form of the application delegate method shown in the question.

Comment: You might have didn't noticed that the 2nd form having a NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, id> * argument, where he want to extract string and id, I've shown how he can extract those things with the perfect output. Please review the question.

Comment: But your answer isn't related at all to the question. Put your answer in the context of the code in the question. Show how to get the desired values from the `options` dictionary passed to the app delegate method.

Comment: Question itself not clearly defined what values he is getting in options. I just shown the idea how he can achieve which might can help him to do so.

Comment: The question is quite clear. See the other answer (along with my comments to that answer).

Comment: Let me comment on the question and ask him what values exactly he is getting in options, and I will try my extraction method to do so, we can see that might definitely work.

Comment: So can you please let me know what values could be on the options.?

Comment: The method in the question is from `UIApplicationDelegate`. Read the docs for the method.

Comment: ya I know about that but options can have any options like from Facebook, instagram or google+. it will very according to the sdk he implemented

Comment: Right. By using the documented keys you get whatever value it has. That is what is needed and passed on. Again, look at the other answer. It is (mostly) doing what is being asked.

Comment: Exactly, that answer is perfectly right, I just given a idea instantly how he can extract it. if you will check my code you will get to know in place of [options valueForKey:@"UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"], he can achieve the result from options[@"UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"]. which I've given in NSLog that's it.

Comment: I will post a perfect answer in other questions, as this was my first experience that giving just an idea is not enough.